# Are there any sort of format and style themes/templates in LibreOffice?

Tags: themes, libreoffice, downloads

I am wondering if there's any kind of predefined or downloadable themes or templates for text formatting styles (Default, Heading 1/2/etc), predefined colors (palettes), bullet styles, etc., in LibreOffce.

If there are, where do I find them and how can I apply them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on the bullets or on a blank part of the page, choose bullets and numbering, then choose graphics.

[image: libreoffice bullet graphics]

For other things, go to tools>gallery.

[image: libreoffice with gallery open]

The other answers I believe have covered the criteria for what you actually asked for.

The themes listed here are downloadable, but you cannot download new "formatting" styles, you have to create them.

---

### You can find some useful additions here:

- http://extensions-test.libreoffice.org/
- http://templates-test.libreoffice.org/

Comment: Isn't there anything like a theme that will define colours for headings, symbols for bullet points et al?

Comment: @Oxwivi: no, and you didn't ask for that explicitly in your question.

Comment: Now that you know what exactly I was looking for, please edit my question which actually asks for what I want. And please edit the formatting styles bit to the top.

Comment: @Oxwivi: can't you do that :D?

Comment: No, I still did not understand my mistake. I asked you to do it, so that I may realize what I did wrong from seeing the corrected version.

Comment: @Oxwivi: lol I'll get around to it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're looking for templates ([LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/features/templates/) or [OpenOffice](http://templates.services.openoffice.org/)). Templates are commonly used to bundle sets of paragraph styles and so on. Usually, template parts as bullet styles can't get organized separately from writer/calc/impress templates, so templates are used with appropriate paragraph styles, for example.

It's possible to define custom colors, but it isn't easy to import / export them. [Here's a description](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=14529&p=67956&hilit=import%20colors#p67956) how to import custom color palettes in openoffice; [EDIT: there are color palettes available for download, also]. The controls to load / save color lists are marked in the following screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Format → Styles and Formatting** (or **F11**)

[image] [image]

Comment: Like I said, formatting and style *themes*, that is predifined colors, bullet styles and such.

Comment: @Oxwivi: you need to be clearer about that in your question then; because I was going to say the same thing he/she did. 
**"I am wondering if there's any kind of predefined themes or templates for *formatting styles (Default, Heading 1/2/etc)* in LibreOffce."**

Comment: @Roland, yes I asked if there were any themes *for* formatting and styles.

Comment: @Oxwivi: That's what he gave you.

Comment: @Roland, that is the formatting and styles available to edit with the default settings. Not pre-defined themes or templates which I would like to try.

Comment: @Oxwivi: sheesh... when you save your styles etc as "themes" that is where they show up.

You cannot download those, you have to create them. The only other thing you mentioned was bullets (and you did it in comments, not even in the question). I'm going to vote to close this question now. When you are ready to ask a concise question, we can start again.

Comment: @Roland, you just answered me that I cannot download or load themes externally (which is a real bummer). I think I'd accept that answer.

Comment: @Oxwivi: lol... triple facepalm for you :)