# Libroffice Colour Palette

Tags: libreoffice, colors

The default color palette almost only have hard colors and the alternative software has some basic colors and them several shades.

To obtain the same effect in libreoffice we must change by hand the colors or there is a way to add more color palettes and we can choose which use?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/59714/20661) is helpful?

Comment: Thanks for that, but I didn't find it in the version I'm using. But also find a way to do it.

Comment: From my experience the problem is that you will have troubles when opening your documents in other installations of libre office, colors are saved properly, but you will not be able to apply them to new elements. This is really a major missing feature!

Answer (score 1):

At this moment I'm using Libroffice 3.5.0 with Ubuntu 11.10 and have follow [this guide](http://iuveaene.wordpress.com/2009/10/07/change-default-color-palette-in-openoffice/) and the changes doesn't take effect.

That because the configurations are in this folder

> ~/.config/libreoffice/3/user/config

and not the old one:

> ~/.libreoffice/3/user/config

I also changed the file from i.uve.a.ene because in his version only shows 8 columns and not 10. From his work I've remove some colors and keep the Ubuntu and Chart. This is the final aspect of the colors in the main menu.

[image: New colors of libreoffice]

Comment: How to find the rgb value for a color which has a name like Cerulean Blue 7?

Comment: maybe (0, 123, 167):  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerulean